# TFS client (web access) license?

Tags: tfs

I heard that even client need license to access TFS, but I found that I can add as manmy members as I like to the 'MEMBERS' and then they can access TFS by web page(they are under the same windows domain).

So do they need TFS client license?

Comment: there are 5967 questions tagged as 'tfs' on this site, I'm surprised to see so many off-topic questions. Also, please rate 'tfs' as an off-topic tag so that people will never ask a question about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't require a license for TFS Work Item Web Access.

More info:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/govdev/archive/2012/05/14/understand-tfs-licensing.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/12c879a8-4d44-4035-8d8f-aeb8055dc1ce/do-we-need-license-to-enable-tfs-web-access-feature

Comment: thank you, you are the reason I come to stackoverflow.com, not the other smarter guys.

Comment: It's my pleasure to be of any help.